# ASP.NET Chart Control - Axis labels

Tags: .net, asp.net-charts

I am trying out [THIS](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) .NET MS Chart control.

Could someone who knows about it tell me how to set the axis labels without using data bindings?

eg. If there are 3 columns, I am looking for something like this

```
Chart1.AxisX.Labels = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does it

```
    for (int c = 1; c < numOfColumns; c++)
      chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel(c - 0.5, c + 0.5, labels[c], 0, LabelMarkStyle.None));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Axis X Name"
```

Comment: That is to set the label of the X axis. I want to set the label for the individual bar